# implementing objective C protocol with initializer in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this objective-C protocol

```
@protocol Parcelable <NSObject>
@required
- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
@end
```

That I can't seem to find a way to implement in a Swift class. I have tried

```
required init(data: NSDictionary) {
    super.init()
    ... //do something with data
}
```

and even

```
func initWithData(data: NSDictionary) -> Self {
    ... //do something with data
}
```

But it keeps saying that the class does not conform to protocol 'Parcelable'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! the correct way to implement this protocol is

```
required init(data: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    super.init()
    ... //do something with data
}
```

Swift translates `NSDictionary` to `[NSObject : AnyObject]` and does not recognize `NSDictionary` itself (?)